# Shell asks me to install IDLE despite it being already installed

Tags: command-line, bash, software-installation, idle-python

I executed this command to open a .py file in idle terminal :

```
idle python_file.py
```

Shell displayed the following message in response :

```
The program 'idle' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install idle
```

I have already installed idle and infact used the same to create python_file.py. Why does shell ask me to install it again? Using Ubuntu 13.10 if it helps.

Comment: What is the output if you run `which idle`?

Comment: @Donarsson I didn't get any output on running the above command

Comment: Can you run `/usr/bin/idle`?

Comment: Shell says no such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `/usr/bin` directory. On my machine at least, IDLE is installed under `/usr/bin/idle-python2.7` and `/usr/bin/python3.2`, so I would open the file using:

> idle-python3.2 python_file.py

Answer (score 2):

From your comments it appears that you don't have IDLE installed, so open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install idle idle3
```

There are two different IDLEs (IDLE 3 is an IDE for Python 3) and that command will install them both.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `idle` isn't in your environment path. To see what directories are in your path, you can run:

```
echo $PATH
```

When you execute a command from the terminal (`ls`, `cat`, etc.) bash looks for the corresponding binary/script in each of the directories listed out from the command above.

You can either install with `apt` as others have suggested, or if you are *absolutely* sure that you installed it on your system, you can try looking for it with `find`:

```
sudo find / -iname "*idle*"
```

Which should help you determine where the binary is. Once/if you find the location of the binary, add it to your path to avoid this same error in the future:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/idle/binary
```

Which can be added to your `~/.bashrc` file.